# Mailserver on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dns, ubuntu-16.04, postfix-mta, mail-server

I'm following this guide on how to install a mail server on Ubuntu 16.04 with postfix:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-on-ubuntu-16-04

The problem is, when I get to step 7, I get the expected error `Can't canonicalize "/home/<user>/Maildir"`

But then when I run `ls -R ~/Maildir`, I get the error `ls: cannot access '/home/<user>/Maildir': No such file or directory`. When I make the directory and run `mail` I get the output `/home/<user>/Maildir: Is a directory`.

On my server, I have an MX record with `Type: MX; Hostname: example.com; Value: mail.example.com; TTL(seconds): 14400`, an A record with `Type: A; Hostname: mail.example.com; Value: <ip_address_of_server>; TTL(seconds): 3600`, and another A record of `Type: A; Hostname: example.com; Value: <ip_address_of_server>; TTL(seconds): 3600`.

The only thing I can think of is that my records are wrong, but everywhere I look, it seems like I'm doing it correctly. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run this, it should work after that.

```
$ sudo postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
$ sudo service postfix reload
```

Every time you edit virtual file, you need to run the above commands.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. There was a wrong reset command in the tutorial.